# Linux text editor w/ text formatting & image support

Tags: linux, images, text-editor, note-taking

A great example of what I'm looking for is Evernote. Its text editor supports text formatting and allows you to insert images in-line.

I've tried LibreOffice, but it's rather bloated and complicated to achieve my rather simple note-taking needs.

Comment: How about one of the RTF editors?

Comment: What about [NeverNote](http://nevernote.sourceforge.net)

Comment: What about typing ["evernote linux" into google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=evernote+linux), and using [one of its Linux derivates](https://blog.udemy.com/evernote-for-linux/) – like jojo's NeverNote, or EverPad, NixNote, SpringSeed, RedNoteBook, GeekNote?

Comment: I've tried Evernote, but I don't want to use it. I'd prefer to see my notes on my desktop and be responsible for backing them up myself, rather than having all of my data on the cloud in a proprietary format.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest taking a look at [RedNotebook](http://rednotebook.sourceforge.net/) it is primarily a journal keeping application but works equally well for note taking:

- #Hashtags
- Format your text bold, italic or underlined
- Insert Images, files and links to websites
- Links and mail addresses are recognized automatically
- Spell Check
- Live-Search
- Automatic saving
- Backup to zip archive
- Word Clouds with most often used words and tags
- Templates
- Export the journal to PDF, HTML, Latex or plain text
- The data is stored in plain text files, no database is needed
- Translated into more than 30 languages
- Available for Windows - [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/rednotebook/files/).
- Linux:

  - Fedora: `yum install rednotebook`
  - Debian: `apt-get install rednotebook`
  - Ubuntu:
    `
       sudo add-apt-repository ppa:rednotebook/stable
       sudo apt-get update
       sudo apt-get install rednotebook
- Mac OS-X
- Small the windows installer is only 23 MB
- Fast and lightweight
- You edit in markdown, *(similar to here but with more options)*
- Portable versions are also available to run from a USB key.
- RedNotebook is Free Software under the GPL.
  `
  [image]

Comment: Is this open source?

Comment: @jojo - Yes! RedNotebook is Free Software under the GPL.